# calculate percentile of 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i have size classes and for each size class i have measured counts:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
size_class = np.linspace(0,9,10)
counts = norm.pdf(size_class, 5,1) # synthetic data
counts_cumulative_normalised = np.cumsum(counts)/counts.sum() # summing up and normalisation
plt.plot(size_class,counts_cumulative_normalised)
plt.show()
```

so if i would like to calculate the percentiles of the size i would have to interpolate my desired size.

Is there a build in function that takes these two vectors as arguments and gives me the desired percentiles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know if the data is normally distributed, and you want to get the percentiles based on the Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function, you can use a interpolation approach.

```
In [63]:

plt.plot(size_class,counts_cumulative_normalised)
Out[63]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10c72d3d0>]
```

[image]

```
In [69]:
#what percentile does size 4 correspond to ?
from scipy import interpolate
intp=interpolate.interp1d(size_class, counts_cumulative_normalised, kind='cubic')
intp(4)
Out[69]:
array(0.300529305241782)
```

I know you are presenting just a synthetic data, but do notice that the way you are doing underestimated the Cumulative Distribution Functions, as you only takes a few sample points, see this comparison:

```
plt.plot(size_class,counts_cumulative_normalised)
plt.plot(size_class,norm.cdf(size_class, 5, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: That is interesting. I will think about that. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: where do i find informations about plotting in StackOverflow ?

Comment: @Moritz, you are welcome and try `matplotlib` tag for plotting related questions.

Comment: Ehm, i meant how do you make this nice plots inside SO. But i see, it was an image you linked to.